# Proving $a\equiv b \pmod{10}$ if and only if $a\equiv b \pmod{2}$ and $a\equiv b \pmod{5}$. Something doesn't feel right.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$. Prove that $a\equiv b \pmod{10}$ if and only if $a\equiv b \pmod{2}$ and $a\equiv b \pmod{5}$

Showing that $P\Rightarrow (Q\wedge R)$:

Assume $a\equiv b \pmod{10}$. Then $10\mid(a-b)$, so $(a-b)=10n, n\in\Bbb{Z}$.

This implies that $(a-b)=2m, m=(5n)\in\Bbb{Z}$ and therefore $2\mid(a-b)$, so $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$.

Conversely, $(a-b)=5k, k=(2n)\in\Bbb{Z}$ and therefore $5\mid(a-b)$, so $a\equiv b\pmod{5}$

Now to show that $(Q\wedge R)\Rightarrow P$ we will show that $\sim P\Rightarrow \sim Q\vee\sim R$.

Assume $a\not\equiv b\pmod{10}$. Then $10\not\mid(a-b)$. This implies $(a-b)\not=10n, n\in\Bbb{Z}$, so $a-b\not=2(5n)$ and $a-b\not=5(2n)$.

Therefore $2\not\mid(a-n)$ and $5\not\mid(a-b)$, so $a\not\equiv b\pmod{2}$ and $a\not\equiv b\pmod{5}$

> Is this a valid proof? Since I'm following the same argument in the second part something doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

Something's gone wrong with the second part of your proof, since you assumed that $a \not\equiv b \,(\mathrm{mod}\, 10)$ and concluded that $a \not\equiv b \,(\mathrm{mod}\, 2)$ **and** $a \not\equiv b \,(\mathrm{mod}\, 5)$. However, there are pairs of numbers, like 0 and 15, which are congruent modulo 5 but not congruent modulo 2 or 10.

You have correctly deduced that $a - b$ cannot be written as $2(5n)$ where $n$ is an integer; however, we could have, say, that $a - b = 2(3)$, since 3 is not a multiple of 5.

Comment: But doesn't the negation of $(Q\vee R)\Rightarrow P$ become $\sim P \Rightarrow \sim Q \wedge \sim R$ ?

Comment: You want to show that $(Q \wedge R) \implies P$ though, and the contrapositive of this is $\sim P \implies \sim Q \, \vee \sim P$.

Comment: Oh whoops, yes I see that. Thank you!